# mosquitto auth plugin database issue

Tags: postgresql, mqtt, mosquitto

I am using [mosquitto auth plugin](https://github.com/jpmens/mosquitto-auth-plug#postgresql) here is my mosquitto.config file

```
listener 1883

#listener 9001 127.0.0.1
#protocol websockets

auth_opt_backends postgres
auth_plugin /etc/mosquitto/auth-plug.so
auth_opt_dbname mqtt
auth_opt_host localhost
auth_opt_port 5432
auth_opt_user postgres
auth_opt_pass postgres
auth_opt_userquery SELECT password FROM account WHERE username = $1 limit 1
auth_opt_superquery SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) FROM account WHERE username = $1 AND super = 1
auth_opt_aclquery SELECT topic FROM acls WHERE (username = $1) AND (rw >= $2)
```

all `postgres` setting are default `postgres` settings.
when I run

```
sudo /usr/local/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

command. I am getting this error:

```
1456228482: mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date 2016-02-22 18:23:09+0530) starting
1456228482: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1456228482: |-- *** auth-plug: startup
1456228482: |-- ** Configured order: postgres

1456228482: |-- }}}} POSTGRES
1456228482: |-- HERE: SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) FROM account WHERE username = $1 AND super = 1
1456228482: |-- HERE: SELECT topic FROM acls WHERE (username = $1) AND (rw >= $2)
|-- We were unable to connect to the database
|-- *** ABORT.
```

If I uncomment these two line

```
#listener 9001 127.0.0.1
#protocol websockets
```

i get this error:

```
Error: Websockets support not available.
Error found at /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf:4.
Error: Unable to open configuration file.
```

I was following these tutorial

[Tutorial1](http://www.kirang.in/2015/05/23/setting-up-acl-in-mosquitto-using-postgres/)
[Tutorial2](http://my-classes.com/2015/02/05/acl-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-auth-plugin/)

after changing password of postgres and chaging the default port 1883

```
1456232627: mosquitto version 1.4.8 (build date 2016-02-22 18:23:09+0530) starting
1456232627: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1456232627: |-- *** auth-plug: startup
1456232627: |-- ** Configured order: postgres

1456232627: |-- }}}} POSTGRES
1456232627: |-- HERE: SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(*),0) FROM account WHERE username = $1 AND super = 1
1456232627: |-- HERE: SELECT topic FROM acls WHERE (username = $1) AND (rw >= $2)
1456232627: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1884.
1456232627: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1884.
1456232627: Error: Invalid user 'mosquitto'.
```

from where "mosquitto" user is comming ?

Comment: You have 2 separate issues here, 1) You can not connect to Postgress 2) No websocket support. They are very unlikely to be related. How did you install mosquitto, did you build it yourself?

Comment: yes i build from source by following given tutorial

Comment: Then the websocket problem is because neither of those links include how to enable websockets at build time and which pre-reqs are needed. You need to edit the obvious bit of `config.mk` and ensure you have the dev files for libwebsocket

Comment: For the postgress problem, have you checked that you can actually connect to the DB with those credential and port number from some other tool?

Comment: i silved postgres issue, but now there is another issue. I updated my question pls look at last paragraph

Comment: Is what you posted your whole mosquitto.conf?

Comment: yes this all my config file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the what has been given in the comment to form an actual answer:

1. The websockets problem is down to not building with Websockets enabled in config.mk by modifying the following line:

   `WITH_WEBSOCKETS:=no`

   And then rebuilding. You will need to ensure you have the libwebsocket development files installed.
2. The `We were unable to connect to the database` error was a database configuration issue
3. `Error: Invalid user 'mosquitto'.` is because you are trying to run mosquitto as root and mosquitto is trying to drop the root privileges in order to safely run at a lower level. By default mosquitto will try to run as a user called *mosquitto*, in this case there is no mosquitto user defined on the system hence the error. You can change the user that it will try and become by adding a the following to the mosquitto.conf

   `user foo`

   This would cause mosquitto to run as user *foo*. You really should not leave mosquitto running as root.

Comment: I was having same issue [Error: Invalid user 'mosquitto'] , added the line 'user root' and the problem is solved. Thank you

Comment: @FerozeMohamed That is the wrong solution, you should either create a mosquitto user or set the `user foo` where is foo is a user you already have on your system. As I said in the last line, you REALLY should not run a root.

Comment: thank you. its just that my embedded system currently only has one user that is root. this is only for development purpose. will remember your suggestion.

Comment: Arrrgh! No, fix that now. Get out of the habit of running things as root straight away, otherwise you will just ended up with something totally insecure